# Function returning dictionary doesn't work correctly with groupby method in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to compute the percentage distribution over the elements and to have the output dictionary comprised of `time_key` as keys and dictionary with elements percentage as a value

I wrote this code

```
def class_distr(x):
    fractions = x.value_counts(normalize=True) # use value_counts normalize instead
    return [dict(zip(fractions.keys(), fractions.tolist()))]

def get_dict(df, col):
    grouped = df[['time_key', col]].groupby('time_key')[col].apply(lambda x: class_distr(x)).reset_index(name=col)
    return {key: value for key, value in zip(grouped['time_key'], grouped[col])}
```

Here is a dataframe:

```
d = {'time_key': {9394: '2019-03-01',
  898: '2018-09-01',
  2398: '2018-10-01',
  5906: '2018-12-01',
  2343: '2018-10-01',
  8225: '2019-02-01',
  5506: '2018-12-01',
  6451: '2019-01-01',
  2670: '2018-10-01',
  3497: '2018-10-01'},
 'target': {9394: 3,
  898: 4,
  2398: 0,
  5906: 3,
  2343: 4,
  8225: 1,
  5506: 0,
  6451: 0,
  2670: 0,
  3497: 2}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
get_dict(df, 'target')
```

Output

```
{'2018-09-01': [{4: 1.0}],
 '2018-10-01': [{0: 0.5, 2: 0.25, 4: 0.25}],
 '2018-12-01': [{3: 0.5, 0: 0.5}],
 '2019-01-01': [{0: 1.0}],
 '2019-02-01': [{1: 1.0}],
 '2019-03-01': [{3: 1.0}]}
```

It can be seen that the inner dictionaries are wrapped with square brackets.
I don't need it, but the `class_distr` function doesn't work correctly without brackets in conjunction with `groupby`.
How can I handle this without additional loop for extracting dictionaries from brackets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can `group` the `target` column by `time_key` then inside a `dict` comprehension iterate over the groups and create key-value pairs where key is the timestamp and value is the normalized distribution of `target` for the corresponding timestamp

```
grp = df.groupby('time_key')['target']
{k: g.value_counts(normalize=True).to_dict() for k, g in grp}
```

---

```
{'2018-09-01': {4: 1.0},
 '2018-10-01': {0: 0.5, 4: 0.25, 2: 0.25},
 '2018-12-01': {0: 0.5, 3: 0.5},
 '2019-01-01': {0: 1.0},
 '2019-02-01': {1: 1.0},
 '2019-03-01': {3: 1.0}}
```